# rails - are my associations correct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am beginning my first rails application and I would just like to make sure that my associations will work like I am hoping. Here is an overview of the models in my application:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
  has_many :teachers, :through => :courses
  has_many :students, :through => :courses
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  belongs_to :teacher
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
  has_many :students, :through => :courses
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
  has_many :teachers, :through => :courses
end
```

The one thing I have noticed so far is that if I try to get the teachers or students in a school it will return the same record multiple times. I am aware I can just call uniq but I would prefer not having to doing that. So I am wondering if there is a better way I can do this.

Comment: I think you should add school_id in teacher and student models, then build a direct has_many association from school to them. you will always get dup records by using HABTM association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were it me, I would not subordinate teachers or students to courses, but to the school directly. Does a teacher not exist without a course? Likewise a student?

And I'd use defined models for linking teachers and students to courses, not the generic habtm -- defined models let you easily store additional attributes - students might have grades for courses for instance.

Perhaps:

School, has many faculty, has many students, has many courses.

Faculty, has many teachings, has many courses through teachings.

Student, has many registrations, has many courses through registrations.

Course, has many registrations, has many students through registrations, has many teachings, has many faculty through teachings.

Teaching, belongs to faculty, belongs to course.

Registration, belongs to student, belongs to course.

Comment: Awesome, this is closer to what I was thinking in my head. Although, would it work to cut out the faculty and teachings and just have teachers? I would like each course to have one teacher but teachers can have multiple courses.

Comment: I think I can achieve what I want with Teacher has_many :courses and Course belongs_to :teacher, but it just seems weird to me that the course belongs to a teacher. To me, it would make more sense semantically for a course to have one teacher, but from my understanding that would add the foreign key to the teacher model so the teacher could only have one course. So is my best option having the course belong to a teacher?

Comment: In my brain at least, teachers don't so much 'own' courses (nor do courses 'own' teachers), but teachers have an association to a course by being assigned to teach it. The teacher can exist without a course, and a course can exist without a teacher. If something were to happen where the teacher of a course had to change mid-term/year/whatever, then ending a current teaching relationship and starting a new one are trivial. I may be casting too broad an interpretation, but I also feel like yours is a bit too narrow. In the end, it's your design, so design to best answer your use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your interest in a unique constraint, you can actually specify the `has_many :through` to only return unique records.

```
has_many :teachers, through: :courses, -> { distinct }
```

Check out [the Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#distinct) on the topic.

Regarding an additional `:school_id`, If a `Student` or `Teacher`'s association to a `School` is defined purely by their enrollment in or teaching of a `Course`, I see no immediate issue with **not** specifying a `:school_id` column on your `Teacher` and `Parent`